# Weird issue with verifying variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code that is supposed to check if a page doesn't exist, or if it contains anything it shouldn't, and for some reason it's throwing an error at me, more specifically 406, if I go to any page other than the home page ($_GET = "").

Here's the code and thanks in advance for your help :)

```
$currentpage = $_GET['a'];
$pages[1] = "";
$pages[2] = "help";
$pages[3] = "work";
$pages[4] = "download";
$pages[5] = "process";
$pages[6] = "safariex";
$pages[7] = "services";

if(isset($_GET) && !ctype_alpha($_GET) && $_GET['a'] != ""){
    header("Location: http://pattersoncode.ca/error.php?ec=406");

}
if (!ctype_alpha($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] != "") {
    header("Location: http://pattersoncode.ca/error.php?ec=406");
}
if ( ! in_array( $currentpage, $pages ) )
{
 header("Location: http://pattersoncode.ca/error.php?ec=404");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do believe this is wrong:

```
!ctype_alpha($_GET)
```

`$_GET` is an array, not a string. `ctype_alpha($_GET)` will always equal false.

You probably want this instead:

```
if(!isset($_GET["a"]) || !ctype_alpha($_GET["a"])) {
    header("Location: http://pattersoncode.ca/error.php?ec=406");
    exit();
}
```

Which should take care of both 406 conditions.

In most cases you also want to do an exit() when you do a redirect.

If possible it would be better to send an actual http response code rather than redirect:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable', true, 406);
```

Comment: How would I go about fixing that then? @Luke

Comment: @Austen: By supplying `ctype_alpha()` with the **string** you want to validate, instead of an array.